# Console window won't stay on screen despite "cin.get();" or system("pause")

Tags: c++, console, program-entry-point

I want the console window that pops up whenever you run a C++ program to stay... but in my code here that's not happening. It just quickly vanishes. What's wrong? Note: I am new to C++.

For some reason it works properly when I use only the `main()` function to hold everything and not have the second one, but for purposes of my assignment I can't stuff everything in to `main()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

ifstream file("maze.txt");
vector<char> vec(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (istreambuf_iterator<char>())); // Imports characters from file
vector<char> path;                      // Declares path as the vector storing the characters from the file
int x = 18;                             // Declaring x as 18 so I can use it with recursion below
char entrance = vec.at(16);             // 'S', the entrance to the maze
char firstsquare = vec.at(17);          // For the first walkable square next to the entrance
vector<char> visited;                   // Squares that we've walked over already

int main()
{
    if (file) {
        path.push_back(entrance);               // Store 'S', the entrance character, into vector 'path'
        path.push_back(firstsquare);            // Store the character of the square to the right of the entrance
                                                // into vector 'path'.
        while (isalpha(vec.at(x)))
        {
            path.push_back(vec.at(x));
            x++;
        }
    }
}

int printtoscreen()
{
    cout << "Path is: ";                    // Printing to screen the first part of our statement

        // This loop to print to the screen all the contents of the vector 'path'.
        for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = path.begin(); i != path.end(); ++i)  // 
        {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
        cin.get();                          // Keeps the black box that pops up, open, so we can see results.
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Let's get things straight. That's a **console window**.

Comment: Maybe you should learn the names of things you're using, if you're going to write software. In Windows, this is the [console window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console), not a *black box*.

Comment: Functions are typically named using camel case: `printToScreen()`. I've seen arguments of global functions starting with a capital as well. Also, your variables should generally exist within your functions and be passed around as arguments.

Comment: It's shaped like a box. It's mostly black :-) Having said that, I did have to ruminate a while on what that actually meant in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your `printoscreen` function. Try adding `printtoscreen();` before the end of your `main()` function.

EDIT:

Also consider changing `int printoscreen(){` to `void printoscreen(){` and correspondigly `return 0;` to just `return;` in this function, as you are not returning anything meaningful, and are ignorig result value in main. So the enitre code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

ifstream file("maze.txt");
vector<char> vec(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (istreambuf_iterator<char>())); // Imports characters from file
vector<char> path;                      // Declares path as the vector storing the characters from the file
int x = 18;                             // Declaring x as 18 so I can use it with recursion below
char entrance = vec.at(16);             // 'S', the entrance to the maze
char firstsquare = vec.at(17);          // For the first walkable square next to the entrance
vector<char> visited;                   // Squares that we've walked over already

void printtoscreen();

int main()
{
    if (file) {
        path.push_back(entrance);               // Store 'S', the entrance character, into vector 'path'
        path.push_back(firstsquare);            // Store the character of the square to the right of the entrance
                                                // into vector 'path'.
        while (isalpha(vec.at(x)))
        {
            path.push_back(vec.at(x));
            x++;
        }
    }
    printtoscreen();
}

void printtoscreen()
{
    cout << "Path is: ";                    // Printing to screen the first part of our statement

        // This loop to print to the screen all the contents of the vector 'path'.
        for(vector<char>::const_iterator i = path.begin(); i != path.end(); ++i)  // 
        {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
        cin.get();                          // Keeps the black box that pops up, open, so we can see results.
        return;
}
```

Comment: It's giving me a "printtoscreen identifier not found" error

Comment: Sorry, my bad... Should work now after my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps if you actually *called* `printtoscreen`, you might find that it executes the code that pauses.

But, in fact, I'd put that `cin.get()` bit at the end of `main` anyway, simply because it's something you have only while running in the IDE. You will probably not want it in the final executable since it's likely to annoy anyone trying to run it.

In other words, remove `cin.get();` from the end of `printtoscreen` and put something like this at the end of `main`:

```
cout << "Press ENTER to exit (remember to remove this from production code)"
     << endl;
cin.get();
```

And keep in mind that you may need to either move `printtoscreen` to before `main`, or provide a prototype for it before `main` (so that `main` knows about it).

Comment: And here I was looking to see whether `istreambuf` leaves newlines in the input buffer and whether Linux has a `pause` command. I really need to get my priorities straight.

Comment: At your not wanting it comment, why would there be a `printtoscreen()` function then?

Comment: The assignment I'm doing is asking me to display the contents of the vector in the console window.

Comment: @chris, the bit I meant you probably don't want in the final executable was just the `cin.get()`, _not_ the printing of the vector. I should have made that clearer, sorry. Hopefully, my latest edit is a bit more explicit.

Comment: @paxdiablo "And, as an aside and irrelevant to your particular issue, I prefer avoiding cout << endl; unless it's really needed." It is neded there as he is just about to request user input with cin.get(); so it would be nice if user got buffer flushed, so he can actually see the entire program output, right?

Comment: @j_kubik, that only flushes the output buffer though, doesn't it?

Comment: @chris AFIK yes, only the output buffer. And that's exactly what we want here. I guess C++ standard tries to keep separate streams (input output and error) as generic files, so there is no way that they could be somehow interlinked.

Comment: It's probably not worth discussing here, bods, since it's not relevant to the question. So I deleted that bit. I thought it would be the same as C in that either cout is line-buffered if "it can be determined to refer to an interactive device, else fully buffered", or reading from cin would automagically flush cout. But I can't easily find anything in the C++ standards docs about this behaviour. ISO C++ is _much_ harder to read than the C one, and that's saying something :-)

Comment: I wouldn't need it to call it, but if i didn't, the printout on cout might still be (partially) buffered, so nNOT on the screen. When code reaches `cin.get();` we need to make sure that everything from the buffer was actually flushed to console, so the user is not seeing empty black screen waiting for button press.

Comment: As i wrote before, the different streams are basically forbidden to be interlinked, so there is no possibility to automagical flushing be `cin.get();`. Wheter it is possible to "be determined to refer to an interactive device" remains an open question, and i would rather not depend on it. And there is no mentioning it in c++ standard cause ISO c++ doesn't enforce any particualr assumptions on standard library implementation.

Comment: @j_kubik, I see your point now. I've had a flaw in my understanding due to not ever having a problem with output displaying. Just using newlines, my output always displays at the `cout`. I've never really had to think about the buffer at all.

Comment: sorry, I must apologize, I was wrong. There is interlinking mechanism, the `tie()` method. Now that I got myself to find it in the c++ standard it turns out that cin is `tie()`d to cout by default, so there is an automagic after all (27.3.1.2). Who would have thought? ;)